# Change shape solid color in runtime

Tags: android, layout, drawable, shapes

I've Drawable xml file which stands for my custom progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/background">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:thicknessRatio="6.4">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke 
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
            <solid
                android:id="@+id/progressColor"
                android:color="#FBB817" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Used here:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="progress" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to change solid color with id `progressColor` at runtime based on some conditions. Tried everything here and nothing works for me. Any suggestions?

I tried to change it like that:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressColor, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

But it doesn't change anything.

I found solution here:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) v.getBackground();
final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressColor);
shape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But this just crash my app.

Comment: Please explain what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, it's not perfect though, but it do the trick.

First make another drawable with different progress color.

progressbar1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/background">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="6.4"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:id="@+id/shape"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
            <solid
                android:id="@+id/progressColor"
                android:color="#111" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Then when you need it, before you draw your progress bar just change the drawable with following code:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar1);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
```